# How to work out whether it will rain in a given time period given percentages at given hours

Tags: probability

Let's say I was given the probability of it raining over the next 6 hour intervals as:

```
5 93 83 28 100 8
```

How would I then workout the probability that it rains during any of those six hours? Sorry, very much a newbie, just trying to get a grip of this

Comment: Can you figure out the probability that it won’t rain? // It depends on the context. If this is just a word problem in an introductory probability class, then there is a clever trick that this problem is teaching you or having you exercise. If you’re doing this for real meteorology, I would not expect these events to be independent, and that complicates the matter. My guess is that this is the former, however.

Comment: Please clarify what "during any of those six hours" means.  After all, since there is 100% chance of rain during the fifth hour, there is a 100% chance of rain *sometime* during that six hour period, right?